# Is there a rule about Questions asking to print a specific text?

Tags: discussion

Mine got closed because it was the same as the Hello World Thread, which isn't the case since the text contains a lot of repeating words and symbols, which are easily compressable. I also got downvoted 2 times without explanation.

Link: [The 64 Bit, 32 Bit.... Meme](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/240131/the-64-bit-32-bit-meme)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing about [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) challenges is that unless your challenge adds something particularly interesting or new to the scene of kolmos, it's likely to be closed. Whether it's a duplicate of Hello World, 10x10 asterisks, rickroll, 99 bottles, etc. is more or less arbitrary.

In this case, this challenge is a short piece of English text. It has some repetitiveness but not enough to make it particularly interesting, especially since the change in pluralization and exclamation marks as well as the words near the bottom means a large part of it can't be numerical/mathematical compression and will jsut end up being standard text compression algorithms / language built-in string compression.

It does contain repeating words and symbols which *are* easily compressable on their own but the challenge is sort of like multiple parts stitched together and with `!` being only one character, the arbitrary exclusion and inclusion of it on different lines means it is probably more efficient to just hardcode it since you can't really compress one byte of data.

TL;DR: The downvotes are probably for the same reason as the closure - it's just not all that interesting and doesn't add much to existing kolmo challenges as a "compress short English text with a few components that make it not totally boring".